# Problema migración app laravel & vuejs cpanel

Tags: laravel, hosting, cpanel

Buen día señores desarrolladores,

Necesito de su ayuda, tengo una app que debo de migrar.
Esta desarrollada en Laravel + VueJS, en estos momentos está alojada en AWS CPANEL, pero debo migrar a CPANEL HOSTINGER. Estoy pasando todos los archivos y base de datos de el AWS CPANEL a CPANEL HOSTINGER, la app no la desarrolle y esos son los unicos archivos que tengo.

En la primera imagen pueden ver el public html y en la segunda lo que contiene la carpeta AppGestorContenido.

Me da error 500.

[image: Primera imagen es el public html del cpanel aws]

[image: Segunda Imagen es lo que contiene la carpeta AppGestorContenido]

Estos son los logs que registró Laravel:

> [17-Feb-2021 21:54:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(/home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

> [17-Feb-2021 21:54:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

> [17-Feb-2021 21:54:27 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher' not found in /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/EventServiceProvider.php:18
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(785): Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider->Illuminate\Events{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
> #1 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(667): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
> #2 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(615): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('events', Array)
> #3 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(767): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('events', Array)
> #4 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGest in /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/EventServiceProvider.php on line 18

Comment: Error Status 500 es un mensaje genérico. Revisa los logs de laravel en `storage/logs/laravel.log` para ver cuál es el error en concreto

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Hola, que pena molestarte.
https://tucachivache.com/errores/error.txt Este es el error que me sale, no entiendo muy bien.

Comment: No es molestia. No estoy seguro, pero al parecer te están faltando algunos archivos en el directorio `vendor/`. Puse el trazo de la excepción en la pregunta, así es más fácil que otros usuarios lo lean y puedan ayudarte

Comment: O también puede ser un problema de permisos en ese directorio. Checka eso también.